# Trouble getting jquery accordion to close all panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I'm working off of an accordion script, some pages have sub pages (about, approach, our work)  and some do not.  If the user is on a page that there is no sub menu, I don't want another sub menu to show either (This is the current case)

The site:
http://thegoodgirlsnyc.com/test/new/index3_7.php

The jquery in the the header:

```
 ddaccordion.init({
    headerclass: "headerbar", //Shared CSS class name of headers group
   contentclass: "submenu", //Shared CSS class name of contents group
    revealtype: "click", //Reveal content when user clicks or onmouseover the     header? Valid value: "click", "clickgo", or "mouseover"
    mouseoverdelay: 200, //if revealtype="mouseover", set delay in milliseconds    before header expands onMouseover
    collapseprev: true, //Collapse previous content (so only one open at any time)? true/false
    defaultexpanded: [], //index of content(s) open by default [index1, index2, etc] [] denotes no content
    onemustopen: false, //Specify whether at least one header should be open always (so never all headers closed)
    animatedefault: false, //Should contents open by default be animated into view?
    persiststate: true, //persist state of opened contents within browser session?
    toggleclass: ["", "selected"], //Two CSS classes to be applied to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively ["class1", "class2"]
    togglehtml: ["", "", ""], //Additional HTML added to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively  ["position", "html1", "html2"] (see docs)
animatespeed: "normal", //speed of animation: integer in milliseconds (ie: 200), or keywords "fast", "normal", or "slow"
oninit:function(headers, expandedindices){ //custom code to run when headers have initalized
    //do nothing
},
onopenclose:function(header, index, state, isuseractivated){ //custom code to run whenever a header is opened or closed
    //do nothing
}
```

})

And the js file:  http://thegoodgirlsnyc.com/test/new/js/ddaccordion.js

I thought I could add a new headerclass - "headerclass2"  and define it as headerbar2 because the menu items that do not have drop down's class name is .headerbar2  and change the line in the actual js file # 37 - 41 to say:

```
collapseall:function(headerclass2){ //PUBLIC function to collapse all headers based on their shared CSS classname
    var $headers=this.headergroup[headerclass2]
    this.contentgroup[headerclass2].filter(':visible').each(function(){
        $headers.eq(parseInt($(this).attr('contentindex'))).trigger("evt_accordion")
    })
},
```

How can I get all of the sub menus to close when the user clicks on a link with no sub menus?

Comment: You're talking about the menu, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're running into is that the state is being persisted because of the setting: `persiststate: true,`.

It looks like what happens is, rather than opening the clicked headerbar (ie. Salons) and closing the other headerbars, it just goes straight to the linked page since there's no submenu. And since you're persisting the state, the open headerbar is staying open on the new page.

So, my suggestion is to use the `defaultexpanded` option, to open the specific headerbar you want opened on the specific page. You could then turn off `persiststate` and let the pages themselves handle which headerbar should be expanded. It may be a little more work, but it will give you fine control over which menus are open by default when visiting the pages.

Comment: I'm not clear on how to use the defaultexpand option.  I've streiend entering page's in the specified location, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MLS1984: Well, according to [this page](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordion.htm) `defaultexpanded` = "Index(es) of content(s) that should be open by default in the format [index1, index2, etc], where 0=1st content, 1=2nd content etc. [] denotes no content should be open by default." I believe that this means that if you pass, say `[3]`, then Salons should be "open". I think it maps like this: About = 0, Approach = 1, Our Work = 2, Salons = 3, Speak Out = 4. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Your solution partially works partially, but when you go to the pages that should have the the sub menus open, they now are closed.

Comment: @MLS1984: Sorry, I didn't say it explicitly, but you have to add an applicable `defaultexpanded` value to ALL pages that should be expanded.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this.  Sorry, I'm new to this

Comment: @MLS: Well, on the About page, you'd set `defaultexpanded:[0]`. On Approach you'd set `defaultexpanded:[1]`, etc.

Comment: @Drackir let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1704/discussion-between-mls1984-and-drackir)