# DDAccordion - Accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

my problems is actually defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766247/trouble-getting-jquery-accordion-to-close-all-panels), however there is no exact solution.

I'm working on a javascript. It's basic accordion menu. however when page is loaded one menu is opened always.

```
ddaccordion.init({
    headerclass: "headerbar", //Shared CSS class name of headers group
   contentclass: "submenu", //Shared CSS class name of contents group
    revealtype: "click", //Reveal content when user clicks or onmouseover the     header? Valid value: "click", "clickgo", or "mouseover"
    mouseoverdelay: 200, //if revealtype="mouseover", set delay in milliseconds    before header expands onMouseover
    collapseprev: true, //Collapse previous content (so only one open at any time)? true/false
    defaultexpanded: [], //index of content(s) open by default [index1, index2, etc] [] denotes no content
    **onemustopen: false**, //Specify whether at least one header should be open always (so never all headers closed)
    animatedefault: false, //Should contents open by default be animated into view?
    persiststate: true, //persist state of opened contents within browser session?
    toggleclass: ["", "selected"], //Two CSS classes to be applied to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively ["class1", "class2"]
    togglehtml: ["", "", ""], //Additional HTML added to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively  ["position", "html1", "html2"] (see docs)
animatespeed: "normal", //speed of animation: integer in milliseconds (ie: 200), or keywords "fast", "normal", or "slow"
oninit:function(headers, expandedindices){ //custom code to run when headers have initalized
    //do nothing
},
onopenclose:function(header, index, state, isuseractivated){ //custom code to run whenever a header is opened or closed
    //do nothing
}
```

then as you see in the above code i set onemustopen = false but doesnt work.

http://thegoodgirlsnyc.com/test/new/js/ddaccordion.js this is the js file but i really confused what will i do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
oninit:function(headers, expandedindices){ //custom code to run when headers have initalized
// not the superior but i get the rid of it like this way
jQuery('.categories').hide();
},
```